# google analytics automatically upgrading to universal analytics

Tags: universal-analytics

It seems that our google analytics has automatically been started to be converted to universal analytics , yet it did not complete.

It says "Property started transfer to Universal analytics processing.

Yet that was three weeks ago.  And it seems to have not completed.

Comment: Did you upgrade your tracking code to the new UA code as well?

Comment: no I did not because on our test server we did not upgrade our tracking code and the switch to universal analytics that we did went through fine without that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528899/upgrading-to-google-universal-analytics/27865736#27865736

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic upgrades can and will happen. Site tracking should not be affected, as the old code is compatible with the newer code, but you'll see changes in your UI and account. To fully use the UA benefits and new features, you will need to upgrade all your analytics tracking code. You can read more about the migration process here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/#phase-2 and
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/guide

Comment: thanks, do you think the upgrade will be completed once we do that ?

Comment: Typically the transfer shouldn't take more than 48 hours, so in your case I would be cautious about it and just to be safe, make a backup of your current code (or comment it out until the new code is working).